# Javascript select string between 2 character

Tags: javascript, string

If I have a string like 1.10.6 or 1.6.5 or 1.33.10, I want to be able to select the string before the 2nd full stop.

So 1.10.6 would be 1.10, 1.6.5 would be 1.6 and 1.33.10 would be 1.33

What's the best way of doing that using javascript please?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and [`Array.Join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: I didn't know is .substring() had an option to select by characters, but it seems that uses fixed positions, not characters.

Comment: @Brad Christie Thanks. .split looks like the option I'm after. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXCeF/)

**For example:**

```
var newString = string.substr(0,string.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: Oh wow. Nice one. I was kind of on the right path, just not thinking laterally enough. Thanks @Naveen. I'll accept the answer as soon as Stackoverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 3):

Going via *Array*

```
var str = '1.10.6'.split('.').slice(0, 2).join('.');
```

Using a *RegExp*

```
var str = '1.10.6'.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
```

Also

```
var str = '1.10.6'.split(/(\d+\.\d+)/)[1];
```

Using two *String* `indexOf`s

```
var str = '1.10.6', i = str.indexOf('.');
str = str.slice(0, str.indexOf('.', i + 1));
```

Using *String's* `lastIndexOf`, assuming only two `.`s

```
var str = '1.10.6', i = str.lastIndexOf('.');
str = str.slice(0, i);
```

Comment: Very comprehensive. Thanks for the options :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/\.\d+\.\d+$/.test(s)){
 return s.replace(/\.\d+$/, '')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = '1.2.3';
var bar = foo.split('.')   // '1.2.3'       => ['1','2','3']
    .slice(0, 2)           // ['1','2','3'] => ['1','2']
    .join('.');            // ['1','2']     => 1.2
```

Break it down in to portions first using split, select only the first 2 portions using slice (starting at the first element [element 0] and selecting 2), then rejoin it again with the periods.

- [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [`Array.Join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = str.split('.')
str = str[0]+'.'+str[1];
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/hTgaZ/